# Android CalendarView slowing down layout

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-xml, calendarview

This is driving me crazy. I have a fragment in my Android app which is laid out using a RelativeLayout. Problem is that for some reason it takes ages to render, about 5 seconds just to load about 4 elements on screen.

One of the elements is a CalendarView and when I remove it it goes back to proper speeds (ie: instant). I'd imagine the problem is got to do with the way I'm asking Android to lay it out, must not make much sense or is inefficient or something.

Here's the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp">

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/title"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:text="TODAY"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 

     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/time" />

<TextView
     android:id="@id/time"
     android:gravity="right"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="11:32"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

     android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_info"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Wednesday, 15th August 2012"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<CalendarView        
    android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="@drawable/white_back_black_border"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried loads of different layout options but removing the Calendar seems to be the only thing that makes a difference.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you doing anything in code with the calendarview? Like setting dates etc.

Comment: Even when I comment out all of the code that deals with it it's still slow. But as soon as I remove it from the layout file its fixed. I reckon it must be got to do with the RelativeLayout because if I remember correctly when I used a LinearLayout it worked fine...

Comment: Heh sure be that way. It just doesn't make any sense. My guess is that  its something else.

Comment: I know it's strange. Just to make sure I switched it to a LinearLayout just there. Works fine, loads instantly. I suppose for the time being I can just live with LinearLayout but it's still annoying me.

Comment: This guy had the same problem: [How to stop Garbage collection in Android 2.3.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356344/how-to-stop-garbage-collection-in-android-2-3-3)

Answer (score 6):

I've had this problem too, both with relative layouts and linear layouts. It doesn't seem to be layout-related.

Here is an example to see the error, just with a simple layout, no code at all:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".FechaHoraActivity" >

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And now just change the linear layout height to:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

With this change the problem is gone, at least in my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2

So it seems it is more "space" related, but I'm still not sure why this problem appears. And I haven't found any other interesting results on google searching "calendarview slow"...

**EDIT** *Let's see if we can find an answer with a small bounty*

Comment: The `CalendarView` `layout_height` also needs to be `match_parent`.

Answer (score 5):

I take some hours to find the answer, but not figure out why. Here is something strange, may it can help you to find the answer.

> the cpu consumption when CalendarView slow
>   [image]

The getView in WeekAdapter has a param parent that was never used.

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       WeekView weekView = null;
        if (convertView != null) {
            weekView = (WeekView) convertView;
        } else {
            weekView = new WeekView(mContext);
            android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams params =
                new android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            weekView.setLayoutParams(params);
            weekView.setClickable(true);
            weekView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        int selectedWeekDay = (mSelectedWeek == position) ? mSelectedDate.get(
                Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) : -1;
        weekView.init(position, selectedWeekDay, mFocusedMonth);

        return weekView;
    }
```

Looking forward the answer.

Comment: How do you view the cpu consumption? Is this in Eclipse?

Comment: Look at [this](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html), it has been integrated in DDMS.

Comment: interesting, we are closer now. I've used your approach to compare two layouts (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17786549/920173)). The first one (the one that hangs): [wrap_content](http://oi42.tinypic.com/30iktar.jpg) And the one than runs fine: [match_parent](http://oi39.tinypic.com/ax0b9l.jpg) As you can see the difference starts at number #4 with "obtainView". Inside that we can see: [inside obtainView](http://oi41.tinypic.com/e7msfk.jpg) Yeah, `WeekAdapter.getView` is clearly the problem, you are right, now we have to find why.

Comment: we still don't know why this happens, but you did a great investigation and I don't want to leave the bounty without a winner so enjoy =)

Comment: Thks TheBronx, this mystery still open , anyone who slove this will be reward.

Comment: got the same problem. sdk 4.2

Answer (score 3):

It seems like CalendarView directly inside a RelativeLayout really doesn't work that well. The following solution with the trick of using a FrameLayout is loading much faster in the emulator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/time"
        android:text="TODAY"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/time"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="11:32"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="Wednesday, 15th August 2012"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_back_black_border" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It is not the FrameLayout that solves the problem, it is the fixed height. Seems android needs the height to build the weeks smoothly...

Comment: I tested this again and used a RelativeLayout instead of a FrameLayout and it took +10sec to load the app. I changed the surrounding layout of the calendarView back to FrameLayout and it loaded instantly again. So I'm inclined to say it has definitely to do with the way RelativeLayout handles CalendarViews.

Comment: Yes true, dont no why relative layout is sucks in rendering cal view. use linearlayout... Thanks bro for help +1 from my side

Answer (score 3):

Found that CalendarView widget needs height to be set to `match_parent`, then you can put it to any layout. For example in relative with height 200. This works fine on 4.0.3 emulator and on Samsung Galaxy Tab with 4.2.2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/cv_dialog_filter_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="05.12.2013" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting the CalendarView in a FrameLayout will solve the problem..
here is a XML code example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cc00b1cc">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <CalendarView
            android:layout_width="425dp"
            android:layout_height="374dp"
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers were right but, still hasn't solved one mystery.

That is, When i want to include calendarview inside layout with other layout. It's just disappears or i can see only Week letters. I tried the above match parent and everything and still i couldn't solve it.

If anyone struggling like me Here's the answer.

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarService"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"></CalendarView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"> 


     ///Your views 


     />
```