# How to stop Garbage collection in Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, performance, garbage-collection, calendarview

I have android application 2.3.3 use calendarView
when press button => show dialog (contain calendarView)

My logcat display:

```
D/dalvikvm(15292): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1988K, 10% free 20024K/22087K, paused 4ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm(15292): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1995K, 10% free 20022K/22087K, paused 4ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm(15292): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1986K, 10% free 20029K/22087K, paused 4ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm(15292): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2005K, 10% free 20023K/22087K, paused 4ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm(15292): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1995K, 10% free 20016K/22087K, paused 4ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm(15292): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1997K, 10% free 20022K/22087K, paused 3ms+4ms
```

It slows down my app...
I think Garbage collection paused my app
Please help me show it quickly!

Thanks!

Comment: Check this [out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484079/how-can-i-avoid-garbage-collection-delays-in-java-games-best-practices).

Comment: I think there is no clean way to achieve this.

Comment: Without debugger app will work much faster.

Comment: Related problem: [Android CalendarView slowing down layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812084/android-calendarview-slowing-down-layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Garbage Collector is a daemon thread. You can neither stop it nor call it. You can just make a request, eg.- System.gc(), to the garbage collector.

Plus, **garbage collector helps improving the performance**.

If you do not want to get your objects getting collected by GC then just **Hold the reference.**

If your object is getting collected prematurely, it is a symptom that you have a bug in the design of your application.

Comment: thank for your answer...i try put dialog calendar into small project, it to quickly.i will clear memory before

Answer (score 1):

When implementing applications (like games etc) that need to `avoid garbage collection` because of the small pauses it introduces every time the garbage collector executes,

`All you can do is avoid to keep on creating objects and try to reuse as much as possible the objects instances you already have.`

This can be done in different ways [**take a look at this**](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/12/coding-for-performance-and-avoiding-garbage-collection-in-android/)

Answer (score 1):

When using CalendarView I noticed one quite surprising thing. When I set calendar heigh as number, ex. android:layout_height="400dp" garbage collector is not run, however when I set it as match_parent garbage collector is run every time I switch orientation. Perhaps that's the answer?

Answer (score 0):

i resolved my problem.
because my dialog have RelativeLayout to contain calendarView.
i changed RelativeLayout to LinearLayout => Garbage collection not start

Thanks!