# Activity skipping 100s of frames? Taking too long to appear?

Tags: android, android-activity, frame

Activity is taking too long to appear. I don't know why,  its has simple layout but 500 frames or more are getting skipped every time. I am not doing any heavy work, its so stupid I am only setting main layout file.

```
package zafus.pointme;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class CreateEventActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_event);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_create_event, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is layout.xml for the activity.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="zafus.pointme.CreateEventActivity">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/create_event_fromal" android:text="Create new event and send invites to your friends and family." android:textSize="20sp" android:textColor="#0099cc" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/recepient"
        android:layout_below="@+id/create_event_fromal"
       android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:text="Send To: "
       android:textColor="#0099cc"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/recepient_contact"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/create_event_fromal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/recepient"
        android:hint="Tap to add recepients"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/recepient"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/recepient_contact"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/create_event_image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/event_picture"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_use"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#0099cc"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:text="Featured Image"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:hint="Event Title"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/recepient"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/create_event_image"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/create_event_image" />




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/when"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#0099cc"
            android:text="When: "

            android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/create_event_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/create_event_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:hint="Comment if any"
         />

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/datepicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/when"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/when">
      </CalendarView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what logcat says:

```
07-17 13:15:18.001      637-637/zafus.pointme D/BubblePopupHelper﹕ isShowingBubblePopup : false
07-17 13:15:18.001      637-637/zafus.pointme D/BubblePopupHelper﹕ isShowingBubblePopup : false
07-17 13:15:18.003      637-637/zafus.pointme D/BubblePopupHelper﹕ isShowingBubblePopup : false
07-17 13:15:18.003      637-637/zafus.pointme D/BubblePopupHelper﹕ isShowingBubblePopup : false
07-17 13:15:18.004      637-637/zafus.pointme D/BubblePopupHelper﹕ isShowingBubblePopup : false
07-17 13:15:18.004      637-637/zafus.pointme D/BubblePopupHelper﹕ isShowingBubblePopup : false
07-17 13:15:18.088      637-637/zafus.pointme I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 372 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 13:15:26.544      637-652/zafus.pointme I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 212268(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 36% free, 28MB/44MB, paused 3.387ms total 136.810ms
07-17 13:15:41.899      637-647/zafus.pointme W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 19.104ms
07-17 13:15:41.912      637-652/zafus.pointme I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 414866(14MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 21% free, 29MB/37MB, paused 2.258ms total 132.690ms
07-17 13:16:45.033      637-647/zafus.pointme W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 7.965ms
07-17 13:17:09.585      637-647/zafus.pointme W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.500ms
07-17 13:17:19.262      637-637/zafus.pointme D/BubblePopupHelper﹕ isShowingBubblePopup : false
07-17 13:17:19.262      637-637/zafus.pointme D/BubblePopupHelper﹕ isShowingBubblePopup : false
07-17 13:17:19.262      637-637/zafus.pointme D/BubblePopupHelper﹕ isShowingBubblePopup : false
07-17 13:17:19.262      637-637/zafus.pointme D/BubblePopupHelper﹕ isShowingBubblePopup : false
07-17 13:17:19.265      637-637/zafus.pointme D/BubblePopupHelper﹕ isShowingBubblePopup : false
07-17 13:17:19.265      637-637/zafus.pointme D/BubblePopupHelper﹕ isShowingBubblePopup : false
07-17 13:17:19.293      637-637/zafus.pointme D/BubblePopupHelper﹕ isShowingBubblePopup : false
07-17 13:17:19.293      637-637/zafus.pointme D/BubblePopupHelper﹕ isShowingBubblePopup : false
07-17 13:17:19.293      637-637/zafus.pointme D/BubblePopupHelper﹕ isShowingBubblePopup : false
07-17 13:17:19.297      637-637/zafus.pointme I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@7dca64b time:14405839
```

Comment: You need to create a new thread

Comment: How big is your image in the ImageView?

Comment: image is 30*30, 816 bytes

Comment: @user4847410 why do I need new thread i am not doing any network or database related work, i am just setting my layout.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some weird behavior with loading `CalendarView`. I recently dealt with the issue in a `DatePicker` by setting `android:calendarViewShown="false"`, which speeds it up nicely. Perhaps you could try this too.

Edit: SO has several questions about CalendarViews performance, for example [CalendarView takes much time for displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721298/calendarview-takes-much-time-for-displaying)

Answer (score 3):

You can find the reason of speed issues like this using the profiler in Android Studio:
[image]