# Calling Calendar class functions produces GC_CONCURRENT messages

Tags: java, android, calendar, garbage-collection

I am writing a little calendar app for Android and I need some functions the `Calendar` class contains (for example: calculate first day of month, current day of month, day of next month, year of a specific Unix timestamp and so on)

These functions are called frequently and they trigger GC_Concurrent pretty often which causes my app to lag.

This is the way I access the calendar functions:

```
private static Calendar cal;

public static int getDayOfMonth(long sec) {
    if (cal == null)
        cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());

    //cal.clear();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(sec * 1000L);
    return cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
```

Is there a better way to access the functions without producing so much garbage or a better way to calculate the things I need?

Comment: Side note: I think your `getDayOfMonth()` should be **synchronized** if you want to ensure that the "singleton" approach works correctly.

Comment: @Jägermeister Actually I think he should be using a `ThreadLocal` over `synchronized`, but yes.

Answer (score 1):

First question: Have you profiled the code? How certain are you that this is the problem? If you **have profiled** and you **are** certain...

---

Have you tried using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/#Why_Joda-Time) or [Joda Time Android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android)?

Java's default support for dates and times is really terrible, generally speaking.

You can do the same code using Joda time by doing:

```
public static int getDayOfMonth(long sec) {
  DateTime time = new DateTime(sec * 1000L);
  return time.getDayOfMonth();
}
```

Comment: I haven't heard of Joda Time, i will have a look for it, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't your code example produce a lot of garbage aswell if it is executed hundreds of times?

Comment: Java 1.7 and later is really good at handling short lived objects like this without doing a full GC. There are lots of articles on the subject [but here's one of them](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/05/g1)

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop stop garbage collection, it is a daemon thread.

It's meant to improve performance; if it's slowing your program, than there likely is a inefficient use of objects/other design flaw causing the garbage collector to have redundant tasks.

I don't want to repeat what you probably already know, but you should look @ this post, it should prove useful.

[Android CalendarView slowing down layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812084/android-calendarview-slowing-down-layout)

-Eric